# Using Adobe Flex for Speed Test

Tags: performance, apache-flex, air, download, adobe

If I were to use Adobe Flex for a connection speed test, how would I go about downloading and uploading the files to and from the server to get timing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getTimer()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29) to compute a relative time.  Just call the function twice, and use the difference between the two calls.  I believe it returns a value in milliseconds.

You can test data transfer in the background, you can do so by using HTTPService, or RemoteObject, WebService, or URLLoader; depending on what you want to download/upload.

If you need to upload a file using User Interaction, then you'll have to use [FileRference.browse()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse%28%29) and/or [FileReference.upload()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#upload%28%29)

Comment: Or, you could use URLLoader to do GET and POST requests. Much cleaner because it doesn't require user dialog interaction

Comment: I added URLLoader to the list of options.  Conceptually; it's not much different than HTTPService, RemoteObject, or WebService.  I thought those classes actually used a URLLoader under the hood.

Comment: Yes they do. But HTTPService is generally used for web services, so a URLLoader is proper for this use-case